# Big O, what is the complexity of summing a series of n numbers?

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, complexity-theory, big-o

I always thought the complexity of:

`1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` is O(n), and summing two n by n matrices would be O(n^2).

But today I read from a textbook, "by the formula for the sum of the first n integers, this is n(n+1)/2" and then thus: (1/2)n^2 + (1/2)n, and thus O(n^2).

What am I missing here?

Comment: It would help to know what "this" is.  You're right that adding up n things (doing something n times, each of cost O(1)) is O(n).  But if instead of adding 1+2+3+ etc you had to *do* something once, and then *do* something twice, and then three times, etc., then after 1+2+3..+n were done you'd have done n*(n+1)/2 things, which is O(n^2).

Comment: Missing? Well you found the formula for a summation which explained it. What else do you need help with?

Comment: @DSM sorry for the ambiguity, the "this" is referring to `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n`

Comment: @user1032613: so just to be clear, the "and then thus" is your gloss, not what the book said?  Because if so, then I think several of the answers below are correct and you're confusing the complexity of an algorithm for summing n numbers in general with the fact that *it so happens* that we can compute the sum of 1+2+..+n using a formula.  Let's say we were summing n squares instead, 1+4+9+...n^2.  The sum of those would be (n)(n+1)(2n+1)/6, but that wouldn't mean that adding n things together would become O(n^3); it would instead mean that in a special case we could get it in O(1).

Comment: This [link](http://courses.soe.ucsc.edu/courses/ams11b/Fall12/01/attachments/13753) is very useful.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776477/trouble-understanding-big-o-notation-for-a-sum-of-n-integers

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) can be used to determine the growth rate of *any* function.

In this case, it seems the book is not talking about the time complexity of computing the value, but about the value itself. And `n(n+1)/2` is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I read in a textbook Karumanchi that 1+2+3+...+k = k(k+1)/2 >n => k=O(√ n).  How this happened. Can you please explain this to me...Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You are confusing complexity of *runtime* and the size (complexity) of the *result*.

The *running time* of summing, one after the other, the first *n* consecutive numbers is indeed *O*(*n*).<sup>1</sup>

But the complexity of the result, that is the size of “sum from 1 to *n*” = *n*(*n* – 1) / 2 is *O*(*n* ^ 2).

---

<sup>1</sup> But for arbitrarily large numbers this is simplistic since adding large numbers takes longer than adding small numbers. For a precise runtime analysis, you indeed have to consider the size of the result. However, this isn’t usually relevant in programming, nor even in purely theoretical computer science. In both domains, summing numbers is usually considered an *O*(1) operation unless explicitly required otherwise by the domain (i.e. when implementing an operation for a bignum library).

Comment: "The running time of summing the first n consecutive numbers is indeed O(n)" - No, it is the running time of adding `n` arbitrary numbers. The running time of summing first n consecutive numbers is the running time of applying the formula `n*(n+1)/2`, i.e. O(1). :)

Comment: @Serge No. “summing the first *n* consecutive numbers” is an *algorithm description*. Contrast that with “the sum of the first *n* consecutive numbers”. The latter is concerned with the result. The former is concerned with the method, i.e. sum the integers one by one. I might have made that more explicit though …

Comment: Of course it is a matter of terminology. And since it is not a formal description but just a conversation it may be context-depended. But in most contexts during a conversation "summing the first n consecutive numbers" or similar is not an _algorithm_ - it is a _task_ (a problem to solve). Not any particular implementation (algorithm) to solve this task but the task itself. And talking about time complexity of the task is talking about time complexity of the best possible algorithm solving it (in conversation because strictly speaking only algorithm may have running time).

Answer (score 10):

n(n+1)/2 is the quick way to sum a consecutive sequence of N integers (starting from 1).   I think you're confusing an algorithm with big-oh notation!

If you thought of it as a function, then the big-oh complexity of this function is O(1):

```
public int sum_of_first_n_integers(int n) {
  return (n * (n+1))/2;
}
```

The naive implementation would have big-oh complexity of O(n).

```
public int sum_of_first_n_integers(int n) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += n;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Even just looking at each cell of a single n-by-n matrix is O(n^2), since the matrix has n^2 cells.

Comment: I think this doesn't explain what is actually being asked: “How come the sum of the first n integers is O(n^2)”?

Comment: The complexity of the first function is not O(1). Multiplication of two n-digit numbers takes n^2 time. Nor does the second function takes O(n) time. the addition is a linear operation for large values of N.

Answer (score 4):

There really isn't a complexity of a problem, but rather a complexity of an algorithm.

In your case, if you choose to iterate through all the numbers, the the complexity is, indeed, `O(n)`.

But that's not the most efficient algorithm. A more efficient one is to apply the formula - `n*(n+1)/2`, which is constant, and thus the complexity is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

So my guess is that this is actually a reference to [Cracking the Coding Interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098478280X), which has this paragraph on a `StringBuffer` implementation:

> On each concatenation, a new copy of the string is created, and the
>   two strings are copied over, character by character. The first
>   iteration requires us to copy `x` characters. The second iteration
>   requires copying `2x` characters. The third iteration requires `3x`, and
>   so on. The total time therefore is `O(x + 2x + ... + nx)`. This reduces
>   to `O(xn²)`. (Why isn't it `O(xnⁿ)`? Because `1 + 2 + ... n` equals `n(n+1)/2`
>   or, `O(n²)`.)

For whatever reason I found this a little confusing on my first read-through, too. The important bit to see is that `n` is multiplying `n`, or in other words that `n²` is happening, and that dominates. This is why ultimately `O(xn²)` is just `O(n²)` -- the `x` is sort of a red herring.

Comment: with "n² is happening, and that dominates" the whole thing made "click", thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have a formula that doesn't depend on the number of numbers being added, so it's a *constant-time* algorithm, or O(1).

If you add each number one at a time, then it's indeed O(n). The formula is a shortcut; it's a different, more efficient algorithm. The shortcut works when the numbers being added are all 1..*n*. If you have a non-contiguous sequence of numbers, then the shortcut formula doesn't work and you'll have to go back to the one-by-one algorithm.

None of this applies to the matrix of numbers, though. To add two matrices, it's still O(n^2) because you're adding n^2 distinct pairs of numbers to get a matrix of n^2 results.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between summing N arbitrary integers and summing N that are all in a row.  For 1+2+3+4+...+N, you can take advantage of the fact that they can be divided into pairs with a common sum, e.g. 1+N = 2+(N-1) = 3+(N-2) = ... = N + 1.  So that's N+1, N/2 times.  (If there's an odd number, one of them will be unpaired, but with a little effort you can see that the same formula holds in that case.)

That is not O(N^2), though.  It's just a formula that *uses* N^2, actually O(1).  O(N^2) would mean (roughly) that the number of steps to calculate it grows like N^2, for large N.  In this case, the number of steps is the same regardless of N.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the first n numbers:

Consider the algorithm:

```
Series_Add(n)

   return n*(n+1)/2
```

this algorithm indeed runs in **O(|n|^2)**, where |n| is the length (the bits) of n and not the magnitude, simply because multiplication of 2 numbers, one of k bits and the other of l bits runs in **O(k*l)** time.

Careful

Considering this algorithm:

```
Series_Add_pseudo(n):
   sum=0   
   for i= 1 to n:
      sum += i
   return sum
```

which is the naive approach, you can assume that this algorithm runs in linear time or generally in polynomial time. This is not the case.

The input representation(length) of n is O(logn) bits (any n-ary coding except unary), and the algorithm (although it is running linearly in the magnitude) it runs **exponentially** (2^logn) in the length of the input.
This is actually the pseudo-polynomial algorithm case. It appears to be polynomial but it is not.

You could even try it in python (or any programming language), for a medium length number like 200 bits.

Applying the first algorithm the result comes in a split second, and applying the second, you have to wait a century...

Answer (score 0):

1+2+3+...+n is always less than n+n+n...+n n times. you can rewrite this n+n+..+n as n*n.

> f(n) = O(g(n)) if there exists a positive integer n0 and a positive
> constant c, such that f(n) ≤ c * g(n) ∀ n ≥ n0

since Big-Oh represents the upper bound of the function, where the function f(n) is the sum of natural numbers up to n.

now, talking about time complexity, for small numbers, the addition should be of a constant amount of work. but the size of n could be humongous; you can't deny that probability.

[adding integers can take linear amount of time when n is really large.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34470364/7713056). So you can say that addition is O(n) operation and you're adding n items. so that alone would make it O(n^2). of course, it will not always take n^2 time, but it's the worst-case when n is really large. (upper bound, remember?)

---

Now, let's say you directly try to achieve it using n(n+1)/2. Just one multiplication and one division, this should be a constant operation, no?
No.

> using a natural size metric of number of digits, the time complexity of multiplying two n-digit numbers using long multiplication is Θ(n^2). When implemented in software, long multiplication algorithms must deal with overflow during additions, which can be expensive. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#:%7E:text=More%20formally%3A%20using%20a%20natural,additions%2C%20which%20can%20be%20expensive.)

That again leaves us to O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to BigO(n^2), because it is equivalent to (n^2 + n) / 2 and in BigO you ignore constants, so even though the squared n is divided by 2, you still have exponential growth at the rate of square.

Think about O(n) and O(n/2) ? We similarly don't distinguish the two, O(n/2) is just O(n) for a smaller n, but the growth rate is still linear.

What that means is that as n increase, if you were to plot the number of operations on a graph, you would see a n^2 curve appear.

You can see that already:

```
when n = 2 you get 3
when n = 3 you get 6
when n = 4 you get 10
when n = 5 you get 15
when n = 6 you get 21
```

And if you plot it like I did here:

[image]

You see that the curve is similar to that of n^2, you will have a smaller number at each y, but the curve is similar to it. Thus we say that the magnitude is the same, because it will grow in time complexity similarly to n^2 as n grows bigger.

Answer (score -1):

answer of sum of series of n natural can be found using two ways. first way is by adding all the numbers in loop. in this case algorithm is linear and code will be like this

```
 int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     sum += n;
   }
 return sum;
```

it is analogous to 1+2+3+4+......+n. in this case complexity of algorithm is calculated as number of times addition operation is performed which is O(n).

second way of finding answer of sum of series of n natural number is direst formula n*(n+1)/2. this formula use multiplication instead of repetitive addition. multiplication operation has not linear time complexity. there are various algorithm available for multiplication which has time complexity ranging from O(N^1.45) to O (N^2). therefore in case of multiplication time complexity depends on the processor's architecture. but for the analysis purpose time complexity of multiplication is considered as O(N^2). therefore when one use second way to find the sum then time complexity will be O(N^2).

here multiplication operation is not same as the addition operation. if anybody has knowledge of computer organisation subject then he can easily understand the internal working of multiplication and addition operation. multiplication circuit is more complex than the adder circuit and require much higher time than the adder circuit to compute the result. so time complexity of sum of series can't be constant.

Comment: I think you are confusing the number of operations with the number of digits in a number. If you set n to be the number of operations, in the first case you have to perform n sums, therefire complexitiy is O(n). In the second case the cost would be O(1) since you are actually performing a known and fixed number of operations (3 in this formula).