# What is the time complexity of adding n numbers

Tags: performance, big-o, time-complexity

If I have to add arbitrary numbers like the numbers 1,12,14,71,83,21... then what would be the time complexity of this operation?

I know that adding two numbers is O(1), but how about a list of n numbers. Assuming I'm using the best possible data structure to store them for this purpose, if at all that can have any impact on the process!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would be O(N). Why does a data structure come into play? You have N numbers, you want to sum them, that is an O(N) operation.

Comment: How so? It would be good to know how this is working.

Comment: You perform an O(1) operation N times, that becomes O(N).

Comment: So the processor really adopts the same naive approach as we would? Add 2 numbers, and then add the next number on to this sum, then the next number and so on.

Comment: The processor only does what you tell it to do. However, you won't find an algorithm for summing numbers that won't process each number.

Comment: Complexity of a calculation is a property of the algorithm, not the processor.   The processor could well do things differently (e.g. break the numbers into a number of subsets, sum up the subsets concurrently, and then add the sums) but would still have to retrieve every value in order to compute a sum.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: In fairness, the *compiler* might optimize to something slightly smarter than a number-at-a-time approach if the processor supports vectorized operations for instance. But yeah, even with a constant divisor (e.g. performing 2, 4 or 8 additions per addition, and summing the partial sums at the end) it's still `O(n)`, you can't process each number without processing each number.

Answer (score 5):

Adding 2 numbers is **O(1)** since the operation itself is constant time and the input is fixed. Regardless of the input, the operation will always take the save time.

Moving to a collection of items, the operation is still constant time, but now it's being done multiple times. The larger the input size (N), the longer it will take, and the growth rate will be linear - for each extra item in the input, the operation will take 1 more cycle.

Because of that, the time complexity is **O(N)**.

Comment: Not so sure that adding 2 numbers is *O(1)*. If the numbers can be arbitrarily large of width W1 and W2 bits, it could be *O(log (max(W1,W2)))* .... If the numbers are bounded (like 64 bits machine numbers fitting in hardware registers), indeed adding them is *O(1)*; bigint arithmetic is not constant time!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - yes you're right, and I guess we could come up with various other scenarios where O(1) would be wrong here but that's not what the question is about, plus O(1) is "given" in OP

Answer (score 4):

It's `O(N)`. Each data-point must be hit at least once.

However, assuming your question is practical rather than theoretical: If you have `N/2` cores capable of adding two numbers in a single cycle, you can perform the operation in `log2(N)` cycles. Pseudocode for a fast parallel approach:

```
while N > 1:
    N = N / 2
    for i in 0..N: // in parallel
        X[i] += X[i + N]
// result in X[0]
```

as opposed to a naive approach:

```
 accum = 0
 for i in 0..N: // in serial
     accum += X[i]
 // result in accum
```

The bottleneck preventing parallelization in the naive case is the 'reduction' into `accum`. I think any commutative reduction operation (addition, scalar multiplication, etc) can be parallelized as above.

Another practical consideration is that CPU and GPU processor cores that can do more than one addition in a single "cycle" (eg SSE).

Big-O doesn't highlight reduction bottlenecks and does not necessarily reflect time complexity measured in *real time*.

Answer (score 1):

It would be `O(N)`. For example in pseudo-code, whereas list contains the numbers:

```
while(list[i] != end) { //n in the size of the list, so O(N)
    sum += list[i]; //O(1)
    i++;  //O(1)
}
```

No matter what the structure is, it would always be `O(N)`, since you must check (add) each and every element.