# How to iterate through a list in Python without using a "for" loop?

Tags: python

I want to print all the elements in the *range* from 2 to 8 then use **for** loop:

E.g:

```
for i in range(2,8):
    print(i)
```

What is the best method to iterate without using a **for**, or **while** loop, which reduces the *time complexity*?

Comment: Use [```str.join```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) along with a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) of the list.

Answer (score 6):

How about using recursion?

```
def iterate(lst, start, end):
  if start < 0 or end >= len(lst) or start > end:
    return
  print(lst[start])
  iterate(lst, start + 1, end)
```

Call it like this:

```
iterate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2, 8)
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Perhaps you should generalize your function for any start and end index.

Comment: @pzp thanks! I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's take this sample list:

```
>>> mylist
['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
```

Now, let's print elements 2 through 8 without looping:

```
>>> ' '.join(mylist[2:9])
'two three four five six seven eight'
```

Here, `2:9` tells python to uses indices starting with `2` and continuing up to but *not* including `9`.

Comment: Thanks! Suppose I have a list of 20 numbers, how do I get the sum of numbers between 2 and 9 without using a loop?

Comment: @Falcon2908 , that's a completely different question. Please submit a new one.

Comment: `x = range(20); sum(x[2:10])`

Comment: @Falcon2908 That's a separate question so you should either figure it out yourself (it's not too big of a logical jump from the code that John1024 gave you) or ask a new question.

Comment: @Falcon2908 Please see my answer to find the sum.

Comment: @Falcon2908, go though a tutorial...https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html

Answer (score 2):

By slicing the list

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> print(l[1:8])
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] # output in console
```

To get the summation of the values in `l[1:8]` use `sum`

```
>>> sum(l[1:8])
35 # output
```

EDIT because of @pzp:

If you want to print all the elements between index 2 and index 8 both inclusive,just replace `print(l[1:8])` in the code above with `print(l[2:9])`.

Comment: Looks like you have an off-by-one error in your slice indices.

Comment: @pzp Nope, I did chose [1:8] on purpose because I want to list 2 to 8 in the list `l`. I know that in Python indexes start at 0.

Comment: The OP asked for "the elements between index 2 and 8" (not value 2 and 8) and your answer gives the elements between index 1 and 8.

Comment: @Ralf17, if you use sum() function, doesn't it behave as a for loop with complexity O (n) ?

Comment: @Falcon2908: You can't  sum a list of `n` elements faster than going through each of the element.

Comment: @Falcon2908 I believe O(n) from `sum` is the fastest during addition in general. The best case scenario, O(1) only happens when you are adding two numbers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470337/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-adding-n-numbers

Answer (score 2):

simple solution using list comprehension

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
sum1 = sum([i for i in list1 if i > 2 and i < 9])
```