# Big-O complexity for n + n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + (...) + 1

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I was wondering.. what is the complexity of an algorithm that starts with n elements (which I run through doing whatever). I take one element off, I do it again.. I take off another element and do it again until I have just one element left.
is it O(n log n)? I can't visualize it...

Comment: That sounds like `!n`, or `triangle(n)`.

Comment: This sum is n(n+1)/2 so it is O(n^2)

Comment: @Henry While I agree about the sum there are n terms here, thus it is O(n), not O(n^2).

Comment: @LorenPechtel no, "which I run through doing whatever" implies you do O(n) work for the first term alone. In total this gives then O(n^2).

Comment: I read it as processing the term in some fashion, not as in processing something that number of times.

Comment: @LorenPechtel if you can process the n Elements in O(1), then you are of course right. But I don't think this is what's meant. Up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it essentially comes down to the math question of what the result of the given sum is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252891/big-o-what-is-the-complexity-of-summing-a-series-of-n-numbers

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The famous mathematician [Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) is said to have found a formula for that exact problem when he was in primary school. And as mentioned by @Henry in the comments it is:
[image]

Source: [Wikipedia (DE)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel), [Wikipedia (EN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

As work is done for every entry, i.e., O(1) is required for each "item". Hence, the problem is in O(n^2).

Visualisation (also [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel)) can be seen as a half filled square:
[image]

Comment: Great answer and visualisation link, really helped :)

Comment: n squared is just the formula that gives you the final answer. How does that make it the time complexity of the algorithm. For example, if you multiply the input by 2 (aka scale it to twice its size), the end result is twice n squared. So as you grow the input, the end result scales by the factor you grow your input by. Isn't that linear ?

Comment: *Note, the above links are from de.wikipedia.org. In Chrome on PC you can click the translate button (to the right of Chrome's URL) to read the page in English.*   
  
Closest English Wikipedia entries I could find:   

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF  
and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: @Gamepad.Coder thx for that, I  added your 2nd ref, as I also did not find a translated version of the German wiki-site.

Comment: @adityah constants are not relevant for complexity evaluation, i.e., scaling by a constant factor can be ignored, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 3):

To solve the complexity for O(n+n-1+n-2....n times), we need to use Sum for mathematics formula by [see this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss)

```
=> n+n+n...n times - (1+2+3...n times)
=> n^2- (n^2+n)/2
```

**Complexity will be**

```
(n^2-n)/2
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, shouldn’t you drop the constant and leave only the dominant term? Hence `(n^2-n)/2` would end up having a complexity of `n^2` or `O(n^2)`. In other words saying that the complexity will be `(n^2-n)/2` is incorrect.