# What is the running time complexity of this algorithm? And HOW do you do the analysis for it?

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity, lowest-common-ancestor

-- The following `lowestCommonAncestor` function finds the Lowest Common Ancestor of two nodes, `p` and `q`, in a Binary Tree (assuming both nodes exist and all node values are unique).

```
class Solution {
public:

    bool inBranch(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* node)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
            return false;

        if (root->val == node->val)
            return true;

        return (inBranch(root->left, node) || inBranch (root->right, node));
    }

    TreeNode* lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {

        if (root == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if (root->val == p->val || root->val == q->val)
            return root;

        bool pInLeftBranch = false;
        bool qInLeftBranch = false;

        pInLeftBranch = inBranch (root->left, p);
        qInLeftBranch = inBranch (root->left, q);

        //Both nodes are on the left
        if (pInLeftBranch && qInLeftBranch)
            return lowestCommonAncestor(root->left, p, q);
        //Both nodes are on the right
        else if (!pInLeftBranch && !qInLeftBranch)
            return lowestCommonAncestor(root->right, p, q);
        else 
            return root;

    }
};
```

Comment: *"What is the running time complexity of this algorithm?"* More that it could be. you traverse several time the same branch to know where are `p` and `q`.

Comment: this one is `O (sqrt (N))`, i.e. naive (brute force) algorithm. Bender M., Farach-Colton M. works in `O(log(N))`

Comment: BTW, about  [run-time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and [LCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `inBranch(root, node)`, you are adding O(# of descendents of `root`) (See [time complexity of Binary Tree Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844193/what-is-the-time-and-space-complexity-of-a-breadth-first-and-depth-first-tree-tr)).  I will assume the binary tree is balanced for the first calculation of time complexity, then look at the worst case scenario that the tree is unbalanced.

**Scenario 1: Balanced Tree**

The number of descendants of a node will be roughly half that of its parent. Therefore, each time we recurse, the calls to `inBranch` will be half as expensive.  Let's say N is the total number of nodes in the tree.  In the first call to `lowestCommonAncestor`, we search all N nodes.  In subsequent calls we search the left or right half and so on.

O(N + N/2 + N/4 ...) is [still the same as O(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

**Scenario 2: Unbalanced Tree**

Say this tree is very unbalanced in such a way that all children are on the left side:

```
     A
    /
   B
  /
 C
/
etc...
```

The number of descendants decreases by only 1 for each level of recursion.  Therefore, our time complexity looks something like:

O(N + (N-1) + (N-2) + ... + 2 + 1) which is [equivalent to O(N^2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252596/big-o-complexity-for-n-n-1-n-2-n-3-1).

**Is there a better way?**

If this is a Binary Search Tree, we can do as well as O(path_length(p) + path_length(q)). If not, you will always need to traverse the entire tree at least once: O(N) to find the paths to each node, but you can still improve your worst case scenario.  I'll leave it to you to figure out the actual algorithm!

Comment: Another case where you can improve things to the sum of path lengths is when each node has a link to its parent. I know that's not always the case, but probably worth it if finding ancestors is a common task. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case the binary tree is a list of length `N` where each node has at most one child while `p` and `q` are the same leaf node. In that case you will have a running time of `O(N^2)`: You call `inBranch` (runtime `O(N)`) on each node on the way down the tree.

If the binary tree is balanced, this becomes <s>`O(N log(N))` with `N` nodes as you can fit `O(2^K)` nodes into a tree of depth `K` (and recurse at most `K` times): Finding each node is `O(N)`, but you only do it a maximum of `log(N)` times.</s> *Check Ben Jones' answer!*

Note that a much better algorithm would locate each node once and store a list of the paths down the tree, then compare the paths. Finding each node in the tree (if it is unsorted) is necessarily worst case `O(N)`, the list comparison is also `O(N)` (unbalanced case) or `O(log(N))` (balanced case) so total running time is `O(N)`. You could do even better on a sorted tree, but that's apparently not a given here.

Comment: If the tree is balanced, the algorithm will actually be O(N) because each child node will have roughly half the descendants of its parent. (See my answer below for details.)