# Find smallest repeated piece of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got some list with integers like:

```
l1 = [8,9,8,9,8,9,8], 
l2 = [3,4,2,4,3]
```

My purpose to slice it into the smallest repeated piece. So:

```
output_l1 = [8,9]
output_l2 = [3,4,2,4]
```

Biggest problem that the sequences not fully finished every time. So not

> 'abcabcabc'

just

> 'abcabcab'.

Comment: Please provide code on what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't got any promising code :(

Comment: @TóthTamás Even pseudo-code would be a start. We are not here to code for you but to help you

Comment: Worth noting that you can solve this in much better than O(n^2).  
I have discovered a truly remarkable proof of this theorem which this margin is too small to contain.

Comment: @Cireo. I think I've found one too. You aren't by any chance looking at the frequency of the first element, are you?

Comment: @MadPhysicist headed in the right direction, you can limit the search space considerably

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding shortest repeating cycle in word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021274/finding-shortest-repeating-cycle-in-word)

Answer (score 3):

```
def shortest_repeating_sequence(inp):
    for i in range(1, len(inp)):
        if all(inp[j] == inp[j % i] for j in range(i, len(inp))):
            return inp[:i]

    # inp doesn't have a repeating pattern if we got this far
    return inp[:]
```

This code is [O(n^2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252596/big-o-complexity-for-n-n-1-n-2-n-3-1). The worst case is one element repeated a lot of times followed by something that breaks the pattern at the end, for example `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8]`.

You start with `1`, and then iterate over the entire list checking that each `inp[i]` is equal to `inp[i % 1]`. Any number `% 1` is equal to `0`, so you're checking if each item in the input is equal to the first item in the input. If all items are equal to the first element then the repeating pattern is a list with just the first element so we return `inp[:1]`.

If at some point you hit an element that isn't equal to the first element (`all()` stops as soon as it finds a `False`), you try with `2`. So now you're checking if each element at an even index is equal to the first element (`4 % 2` is `0`) and if every odd index is equal to the second item (`5 % 2` is `1`). If you get all the way through this, the pattern is the first two elements so return `inp[:2]`, otherwise try again with `3` and so on.

You could do `range(1, len(inp)+1)` and then the `for` loop will handle the case where `inp` doesn't contain a repeating pattern, but then you have to needlessly iterate over the entire `inp` at the end. And you'd still have to have to have `return []` at the end to handle `inp` being the empty list.

I return a copy of the list (`inp[:]`) instead of the list to have consistent behavior. If I returned the original list with `return inp` and someone called that function on a list that didn't have a repeating pattern (ie their repeating pattern is the original list) and then did something with the repeating pattern, it would modify their original list as well.

```
shortest_repeating_sequence([4, 2, 7, 4, 6])  # no pattern
[4, 2, 7, 4, 6]
shortest_repeating_sequence([2, 3, 1, 2, 3])  # pattern doesn't repeat fully
[2, 3, 1]
shortest_repeating_sequence([2, 3, 1, 2])     # pattern doesn't repeat fully
[2, 3, 1]
shortest_repeating_sequence([8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8])
[8, 9]
shortest_repeating_sequence([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
[1]
shortest_repeating_sequence([])
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a rework of *your* solution that addresses some issues:

1. Your solution as posted doesn't handle your own `'abcabcab'` example.
2. Your solution keeps processing even after it's found a valid result, and then filters through both the valid and non-valid results.  Instead, once a valid result is found, we process and return it.  Additional valid results, and non-valid results, are simply ignored.
3. @Boris' issue regarding returning the input if there is no repeating pattern.

**CODE**

```
def repeated_piece(target):
    target = list(target)
    length = len(target)

    for final in range(1, length):
        result = []

        while len(result) < length:
            for i in target[:final]:
                result.append(i)

        if result[:length] == target:
            return result[:final]

    return target

l1 = [8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8]
l2 = [3, 4, 2, 4, 3]
l3 = 'abcabcab'
l4 = [1, 2, 3]

print(*repeated_piece(l1), sep='')
print(*repeated_piece(l2), sep='')
print(*repeated_piece(l3), sep='')
print(*repeated_piece(l4), sep='')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
89
3424
abc
123
%
```

You can still use:

```
print(''.join(map(str, repeated_piece(l1))))
```

if you're uncomfortable with the simpler Python 3 idiom:

```
print(*repeated_piece(l1), sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

```
target = [8,9,8,9,8,9,8]
length = len(target)
result = []
results = [] * length
for j in range(1, length):
    result = []
    while len(result) < length:
        for i in target[:j]:
            result.append(i)
    results.append(result)
final = []
for i in range(0, len(results)):
    if results[i][:length] == target:
        final.append(1)
    else:
        final.append(0)

if 1 in final:
    solution = results[final.index(1)][:final.index(1)+1]
else:
    solution = target

int(''.join(map(str, solution)))
```

> 'result: [8, 9]'.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Solution:

```
def get_unique_items_list(some_list):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(some_list)):
        if not some_list[i] in new_list:
            new_list.append(some_list[i])
    return new_list

l1 = [8,9,8,9,8,9,8]
l2 = [3,4,2,4,3]

print(get_unique_items_list(l1))
print(get_unique_items_list(l2))

#### Output ####
# [8, 9]
# [3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great, but the l2 result is wrong. Because if you repeat [3,4,2], the next element is 3, but in my example, the next element is 4. So the correct answer is [3,4,2,4]

Comment: You mean, you want to detect the complete sequence or number of sequences instead of uniquely repeated values right?

Comment: Can you share couple of test cases to make the problem more clear?

Comment: I would like the smallest piece, that you repeat and cut somewhere, you get the answer.
So for example:
19391 --> 1939 (because if you continue with the first element, you will get back the original number, 
13413413 --> 134, 
11111 --> 1