# How to find Big O Notation of this function?

Tags: big-o

```
for ( i =0; i < n ; i ++) {
    if ( i %2==0) {
      for ( j =0; j < i ; j ++) {
         System . out . println ( " Hi " );
  }
 }
}
```

How would I find the big O  notation of this code?

Comment: O(N²), of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You figure out how many times you need to do each operation in terms of n operations and remove the constants.

The outermost loop, `for ( i =0; i < n ; i ++) {` changes the value of i which is used in the innermost loop.

The if statement `if ( i %2==0) {` means the inner loop will run n by a constant of 1/2 so you can ignore it, it is just a constant.

Ignoring the if statement, the final inner loop, `for ( j =0; j < i ; j ++) {` runs 1+2+3+4+...+n times which equals n(n+1)/2 times. Ignoring the constants, that's n^2.

O(n^2)

Resources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF and [Big O, what is the complexity of summing a series of n numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252891/big-o-what-is-the-complexity-of-summing-a-series-of-n-numbers)