# How is Summation(n) Theta(n^2) according to its formula but Theta(n) ij we just look at it as a single for loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Our prof and various materials say Summation(n) = (n) (n+1) /2 and hence is theta(n^2). But intuitively, we just need one loop to find the sum of first n terms! So, it has to be theta(n).I'm wondering what am I missing here?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377282/can-someone-explain-how-big-oh-works-with-summations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these answers are misunderstanding the problem just like the original question:  The point is not to measure the runtime complexity of an *algorithm for summing integers*, it's talking about how to reason about the complexity of an algorithm which takes `i` steps during each pass for `i` in `1..n`.  Consider insertion sort:  On each step `i` to insert one member of the original list the output list is `i` elements long, thus it takes `i` steps (on average) to perform the insert.  What is the complexity of insertion sort?  It's the sum of all of those steps, or the sum of `i` for `i` in `1..n`.  That sum is `n(n+1)/2` which has an `n^2` in it, thus insertion sort is O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

The running time of the this code is `Θ(1)` (assuming addition/subtraction and multiplaction are constant time operations):

```
result = n*(n + 1)/2 // This statement executes once
```

The running time of the following pseudocode, which is what you described, is indeed `Θ(n)`:

```
result = 0
for i from 1 up to n:
    result = result + i // This statement executes exactly n times
```

Here is another way to compute it which has a running time of `Θ(n²)`:

```
result = 0
for i from 1 up to n:
    for j from i up to n:
        result = result + 1 // This statement executes exactly n*(n + 1)/2 times
```

All three of those code blocks compute the natural numbers' sum from `1` to `n`.

This `Θ(n²)` loop is probably the type you are being asked to analyse. Whenever you have a loop of the form:

```
for i from 1 up to n:
    for j from i up to n:
        // Some statements that run in constant time
```

You have a running time complexity of `Θ(n²)`, because those statements execute exactly `summation(n)` times.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the point here. So, Summation(n) is actually theta(n) , isn't it?! Because, the formula just gives the final result and it's immaterial here.

Comment: @AnoopDixith The time to calculate `Summation(n)` varies depending on how it's done, and can be done in `Θ(1)` using the closed forumla. The mathematical function `Summation` itself is `Θ(n²)`, because it's output grows proportionally to `n²`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're incorrectly assuming that the summation formula has time complexity theta(n^2).

The formula has an n^2 in it, but it doesn't require a number of computations or amount of time proportional to n^2.

Summing everything up to n in a loop would be theta(n), as you say, because you would have to iterate through the loop n times.

However, calculating the result of the equation n(n+1)/2 would just be theta(1) as it's a single calculation that is performed once regardless of how big n is.

Answer (score 0):

Summation(n) being n(n+1)/2 refers to the sum of numbers from 1 to n. Which is a mathematical formula and can be calculated without a loop which is O(1) time. If you iterate an array to sum all values that is an O(n) algorithm.